# «Практика сменилась на организацию» — возможно ли?

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов

> И несмотря на то, что вскоре эта практика — разносить зелень по
>   квартирам — сменилась на организацию рынков (теперь хозяйке можно было
>   выходить и покупать снедь разом), всё же «заведение для зеленщиков» не
>   закрылось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Требует правки. Практика разносить зелень по квартирам сменилась на другую практику - **продавать товары на рынке**. Или прекратилась из-за появления рынков. Пожалуй, это точнее передает мысль автора:

**И несмотря на то, что вскоре эта практика – разносить зелень по квартирам – прекратилась в связи с появлением рынков (теперь хозяйке можно было выходить и покупать снедь разом), всё же «заведение для зеленщиков» не закрылось.**

Немного смушает "теперь хозяйке можно было выходить", как будто ей раньше нельзя было выходить (запрещали?). И еще. Лучше сказать "**всю** снедь разом".

Улучшенный вариант:

**И несмотря на то, что вскоре эта практика – разносить зелень по квартирам – прекратилась в связи с появлением рынков (теперь хозяйка могла покупать всю снедь разом), всё же «заведение для зеленщиков» не закрылось.**

Comment: Это изменение смысла. "Практиковали" зеленщики, а рынки открыл город.

Comment: Тогда эта практика прекратилась из-за организации рынков

Comment: Впрочем, я говорю не об организации рынков, а о продаже на рынках: зеленщики стали продавать на рынке место того, чтобы разносить по домам

Comment: М_Г, не чуешь, что "в связи" канцелярщиной попахивает? Беру: *эта практика прекратилась с организацией рынков*!

Comment: Согласен, так лучше. Чутье чуток подвело :)

Comment: Но мне больше по душе "с появлением рынков", если организация, то кем организовано?

Comment: Автор ВСЁ увидит! )))